# Reset Usage limit per user every month in woocommerce coupon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to allow customer to use coupon only once every month
I set the Usage limit per user =1, But it only works once. How can programmatically update Usage limit per user every month ??

Eg: if customer used "discount40" coupon will not be able to use it again for a month.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think this is how woocommerce expects the coupons to work. Coupon is checked at checkout if user have order with that coupon code. So you have to edit all orders that have this code to something else and then the code will be available to the user that already have it used.

Comment: Why not automate a code creation each month and if customer is logged in at dashboard to say : "hey for this month this is your discount code" . Even you can automate email to notify your customers.  Then at the end of the month grab that code and delete it. Simple and effective solution :)